# Ribbon heading without extending scrolling area

Tags: css, header, scrollbar, ribbon, viewport

I'm implementing a simple ribbon-like heading that extends off the content area (both left and right) displaying a 3d effect with an image background (no css3 tricks).

I tried floating, negative margins and finally relative positioning but my problem is that all the solutions I tried increased the content's scrollable width (extending it to the right). I'd like to keep my ribbon as a "background effect" keep the content's scrollable width.

Check out my simplified working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5cVG/16/

```
body {
    background: blue;
}

body>div {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
}

body>div>p {
    padding: 5px;
}

body>div>h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 20px 5px;
    background: red;
    width: 190px;
    left: -15px;
    position: relative; 
}
```

If you set the viewport width below 215px, you can see that the left-edge extension of the red "ribbons" stay outside of the viewport, and cannot be scrolled inside using the horizonal scollbar.

I'd like to get the same effect on the right-edge extension (overflowing the white area), but it pushes the right edge of the scrollable area and makes itself scrollable.

Any help or demo would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution that looks fine for me in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650215/2084434 (answer by Nikolaos Dimopoulos)

Wrapping the whole content in another div and applying

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

works OK.
Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jJaxp/2/