# two absolute divs; one make scrollbar appear; one does not

Tags: html, css

Here is my site:
http://bible.preahkumpii.com
Once the page loads (it's a web app), you will see two absolute positioned divs in the `#main` div. The `#selector` div is hidden with `left:-100%`, and the scrollbar does not appear. The other div, `#searcher`, is a sibling, and it is positioned similarly with `right:-100%`. But, as you can see, the x scrollbar is activated because of the `#searcher` div being there. I do not want that. I want it to work exactly the same as the `#selector` div, in which it is hidden entirely (scrollbar and all) until the user activates it. Both of these are animated into view using jQuery on click.

```
#selector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 50;
}
#searcher {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: 'Battambang';
    font-size: 120%;
    right: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just add `overflow-x:hidden` to the `body` element:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You should probably implement a back button though.

Comment: Back button, NYI. Let me try it out.

Comment: That was it. I should have known better. Oversight. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Though, I am curious why the `#selector` div didn't cause the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: @preahkumpii That's because it's on the left side. Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284562/absolutely-positioned-div-on-right-causing-scrollbar-when-the-left-doesnt).